# Rename Model field and it's occurrence in whole project

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have model called `Foo` and it has field name `name` and now I want to rename to `first_name` and also it's occurrence in whole project where Foo is called with name field.

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

to

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: Why right clicking on project name and selecting replace in path does not work?

Comment: I want to know if I can do refactor rather than filter and replace.